# R - Function that accesses a variable defined in another function on the same level

Tags: r

So I'm in the middle of a project at the moment, and I've encountered a problem with scoping. Below is a simplification of my problem.

```
a <- function() {
  x <- 1:3    ## x is defined in a()
  w <- d()
  x
  w
}

b <- function() {
  y <- x[2]   ## I want to access x from b()
  x <- x[-2]  ## and modify x
  return(y)
}

d <- function() {
  z <- b()    ## then call b() from d()
  return(list(1, z, 3, 4))
}
a()
```

When I run `a()`, the ideal output would be `w` equal to `list(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `x` equal to `c(1, 3)` . I am aware that I could define `x` globally, however `x` should be 'invisible' to `d()`.
I have tried using `parent.frame()` in `b()`, but it doesn't work, probably because `d()` is its parent and not `a()`. I have also messed around with `environment()`, but I'm having trouble understanding the structure.

Comment: Why not just pass parameters? Also, `b` has its own environment, so even if you get a copy of `x` in there, you're only modifying the copy, not the original, unless you use more complicated methods than `<-`.

Comment: Hi, I'm sort of new to functional programming, can you explain how you would go about passing parameters?

Comment: At its simplest, chopping out the parts that aren't doing anything, `a <- function() {
  d(1:3)
};

b <- function(x) {
  x[2]
};

d <- function(x) {
  list(1, b(x), 3, 4)
};
a()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) local environment** We can define the functions in a local environment which shares `x`.  Since `x`,  `b` and `d` are only used internally we only need to provide `a` back to the workspace.

```
a <- local({
  x <- NULL
  b <- function() { y <- x[2]; x <<- x[-2]; y }  
  d <- function() { z <- b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) }
  function() { x <<- 1:3; d() }
})
```

giving:

```
> x  # x should not be visible
Error: object 'x' not found

> a()
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

**2) nested functions** Another approach is to nest the functions:

```
a <- function() {
  b <- function() { y <- x[2]; x <<- x[-2]; y }  
  d <- function() { z <- b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) }
  x <- 1:3
  d() 
}
a()
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

**3) Using object models**

Although this allows us to run `a` without having `x` visible it may be preferable to use one of the R object models to define an object in which `a`, `b` and `d` are methods of that object and `x` is a property.

The proto package implements a pure object based model (i.e. no classes) which seems particularly approrpiate here:

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(x = NULL,
     b = function(.) { y <- .$x[2]; .$x <- .$x[-2]; y},
     d = function(.) { z <- .$b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) },
     a = function(.) { .$x <- 1:3; .$d() }
)
p$a()
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

The proto code can also be written in the style of (1) and (2) but then inheritance won't work.  Since we don't use that here anyways it may not matter.

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(x = NULL,
     b = function(.) { y <- x[2]; x <<- x[-2]; y},
     d = function(.) { z <- b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) },
     a = function(.) { x <<- 1:3; d() }
)
p$a()
```

**4) Making x invisible to d**  If you really want to make `x` not visible to `d` then for (1) change it to this:

```
L <- local({
  x <- NULL
  list(b = function() { y <- x[2]; x <<- x[-2]; y },
       a = function() { x <<- 1:3; d() })
})
d <- function() { z <- L$b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) }
L$a()
```

Actually if `d` really wanted to get to `x` it could access it like this; however, one would really have to make an effort:

```
environment(a)$x
```

For (2) we would change the code to this:

```
L <- function() {
  x <- NULL
  list(b = function() { y <- x[2]; x <<- x[-2]; y },
       a = function() { x <<- 1:3; d() })
}
L <- L()
d <- function() { z <- L$b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) }
L$a()
```

Again it is actually possible for `d` to access `x` but, again, it requires considerable effort:

```
environment(L$a)$x
```

For (3) we change the code to this:

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(.x = NULL,
     b = function(.) { y <- .$.x[2]; .$x <- .$.x[-2]; y},
     a = function(.) { .$.x <- 1:3; d() }
)
d = function() { z <- p$b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) }
p$a()
```

As with (1) and (2) with some effort we can access `x` from `d` if we really want via:

```
p$.x
```

but accessing a dot variable from outside its object would be quite noticeable.

**Note:** Based on comment you might prefer this:

```
e <- local({ 
     self <- environment()
     x <- NULL
     a <-  function() { self$x <- 1:3; d(self) }
     b <- function() { y <- x[2]; self$x <- x[-2]; y }  
     self
})
d <- function(e) { z <- e$b(); list(1, z, 3, 4) }
e$a()
```

This makes it clear that `e` is identified as an object of which `a` and `b` are methods and `x` is a property and `d` is acting on the passed environment.  It also avoids the ugly  `environment(a)$b()` referred to in the comment.

Although less preferred, you could omit the argument to `d` and just hard code `e` into `d`.  Note that `d` can access `x` via `e$x` so it is not truly invisible but one would have to go to the extra effort of qualifying it.  The reason this is less preferred is that by hard-coding `e` into `d` we are tying `d` to `e`. In that case it would be more logical to just put `d` right in `e` since it is tied to anyways. On the other hand, if we pass `e` to `d` then `d` is not tied to any particular environment.

Comment: Thank you for this! I ended up using method 1), but defining `d()` outside of the `local()` and calling `b()` from it with `environment(a)$b()`

Comment: See Note added at end.